# Lotus notes sends emails in debug mode

Tags: c#, asp.net, lotus-notes

I use Lotus notes to send emails in my ASP.NET and C# web application. It sends emails when its in debug mode however if I publish in my local IIS server it does not send any emails.

```
Domino.NotesSession oNotesSession = null; ;
Domino.NotesDatabase oNotesDatabase = null;
Domino.NotesDocument oNotesDocument = null;
Domino.NotesDocument oNotesDocumentForOther = null;
object oItemValue = null;
bool flag = false;

try
{
    String UserName = "";
    try
    {
        oNotesSession = new Domino.NotesSession();
    }
}
```

I get below error in the above line

> {System.OutOfMemoryException: Retrieving the COM class factory for
>   component with CLSID {29131539-2EED-1069-BF5D-00DD011186B7} failed due
>   to the following error: 8007000e.

Comment: Please share more info and some code if possible.

Comment: I have added the code snippet

Comment: Does your IIS server have Lotus Notes installed?

Comment: Lotus Notes installed in my local m/c (ie I Use Lotus notes for my official mails)

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the Lotus Notes COM DLLs or notes.ini file are not available to the account under which IIS is running.  Can you change your IIS app pool to run under your account (the same account you use to access Lotus Notes?)

Alternatively, if you're just sending emails, is there any chance you can take the Lotus Notes client out of the picture entirely and just send via SMTP to the Lotus Notes server (or any other SMTP server in your domain?)

Answer (score 0):

Ken is almost certainly correct, however there's another thing to consider.  If you are intending to deploy your ASP project on a 64 bit server, you should be aware that the Domino Interop COM classes are not available as 64 bit code and the 32 bit version is [not supported](http://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21454291) by IBM on Win64.  It is possible to make it work for some purposes by installing Domino and manually registering the DLL for the classes, but there are known problems with some of the methods in the classes, and IBM is not planning on fixing them.

So I agree that you would be much better off writing your code to send SMTP messages.